Finding the current between two branches of resistors

The task is to find the current between P and Q if there was a wire connecting them. In another similar question there's just an ammeter between them and you're supposed to find how much current it will measure.
I've been wondering about this question for weeks now and I still have no idea what do. It was a while I studied electric circuits and my memory isn't serving me well. My friend thought that since the ammeter has no resistance, all the current will flow through it and some resistors won't experience any current. He thought you could delete the 15 and 40 resistors and just calculate the current in the remaining circuit. But that didn't yield the correct answer which is 0.31 A.
What's bewildering is this question is from early high school physics. So somebody using only Ohm's law, Kirchhoffs laws, parallel and series resistor calculations is expected to solve this using nothing else.

So do you have a question about the circuit? At least your friend's solution is completely wrong, you can't remove any resistors, current will flow through all resistors. You can simply draw the wire there and then calculate the current through the wire.

What's the voltage at P? What's its effective output resistance? The voltage at Q? And its effective output resistance?

Are you familiar with Thevenin theorem based analysis? It seems to be the most appropriate method to deal with this question.

Re-draw it as 2 separate 24 V voltage sources, one with the 25, 15 Ω branch and the other with the 40, 8 Ω branch. Find the Thevenin equivalent at nodes P and Q, and then connect them. The current will be trivial to find at that point.

@EugeneSh. Yes but like I said this is from an early physics book from high school. We call is physics 1 in Sweden and it doesn't teach the Thevenin theorem, only rudimentary circuit analysis such as Ohm's law and Kirchhoff.

If there is a wire between P and Q, that becomes a new node, therefore you have two sets of parallel resistors in series with each other.

From here it is a simple matter of: 

calculating the equivalent resistance of R1||R2 + R4||R5
using Ohm's law to find the total current
using Ohm's law to find the voltage across each of the sets of parallel resistors
using Ohm's law to find the current through each of the four resistors
finally, comparing i1 to i4 or i2 to i5 to find i3 (it's the difference).


You're solution yields the correct answer but how did you figure out the direction of i3? Also, shouldn't the resistor current flow in the other direction? I realize that there's a ground on the left-hand side, but based on the orientation of the battery, the potential is lower when going to the right. Therefor, shouldn't the general direction of the current be counter clockwise? Still, I don't really understand how the direction of i3 would be in that case either.

@ShootinLemons judging by the GND symbol the battery is the opposite orientation of how you're interpreting it, I think its just a poor drawing. It doesn't affect the current values you get though, just the polarity. You can draw current as flowing whichever direction you want as long as you are consistent with polarity. The direction of i3 comes from the final step - assuming current flows from right to left, if i2>i5 then current must flow up, from Q to P. If if i2<i5 then current must flow down, from P to Q. Same for i1>i4 and i1<o4 respectively.

The way i3 is drawn here, assuming the other currents are positive, the current you calculate for i3 will be negative (that is, the current actually flows upward, not downward.) But that's fine as long as you understand how to interpret the sign you end up with. If that bothers you, you can determine the direction in advance (to decide how to draw the arrow) by calculating what the voltage difference between the two points would have been before adding the wire.

@GlennWillen As mentioned, connecting the GND to the positive terminal may be just poor drawing of as intended, to be confusing in the exercise. For this reason, all the other currents are actually negative, and i3 is correct. If the other currents were drawn in the correct direction, this would be clear: the smaller resistance paths are 25 and 8.

@devnull its misleading to say there's a "correct" direction to draw the currents. I drew them how I drew them, if current happens to flow in the opposite direction than it is a negative current according to my drawing.
